# Input of my python function gives namerror: name "b" is not defined

Tags: python

When I define a function I want my input to just be like "b3" for example, not in brackets. But whenever my input has any kind of letter for example func(b)
it says name "b" is not defined.

```
def position(x) :
y=[]
a=str(x)
   if a[0]==b :
   y.append(0)
   else: 
   y.append(1)
   return y
```

So basically I want position(b3) to give me [0] but went I put position(b3) is says "b3" is not defined

Comment: But b is *not* defined. Where do you think you define it?

Comment: You don't want to compare with the non-existing variable `b` but with the string `"b"`. And please fix the indentation of the code in your question.

Comment: Works as designed, variable `b` does not exist.

Comment: Okay thanks I changed the b in my code to "b" to compare it to the string. But when I enter position(b) or position(b3) it stills gives me " " is not defined. I dont understand how/why I am suppose to define it if I just want it as a string input of my function

Comment: What do you expect `position(b3)` to do if you haven't assigned a value to the variable `b3`? It should be `position("b3")`

Answer (score 0):

change you code to this:

```
def position(x) :
    y=[]
    a=str(x)
    if a[0]=='b' : # is a variable and it's not defined but 'b' is a string
        y.append(0)
    else: 
        y.append(1)
    return y
```

Comment: Okay thanks I changed the b in my code to "b" to compare it to the string. But when I enter position(b) or position(b3) it stills gives me " " is not defined. I dont understand how/why I am suppose to define it if I just want it as a string input of my function

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar mentions in the comments:

> What do you expect `position(b3)` to do if you haven't assigned a value to the variable `b3`? It should be `position("b3")`

All I needed to do was change my input from position(b3) to position("b3") and it works.